# Angular - Adding content to the page

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I've been coding an Angular App which is supposed to be a web-magazine, where you can read some news, reviews etc. In my app I also want to have an admin pannel, in which I want to manage the content of the articles and photos in it (news etc). Do Angular have any lib supporting such operations? By 'adding articles' I mean something like posting a question on eg. StackOverflow, where you can **bold the text** add *emphasized text*, photos etc.

Comment: https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/ you can check this.

Comment: @AbdulBasit is it compatible with Angular?

Comment: Yes it is. I have used it with Angular. 
https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/angularjs-2-4/

Comment: froala is nice but paid. You might want to try [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill)

Comment: You also have this available option: [https://ckeditor.com/](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html)

Comment: @Rotten_Banana I have solution for your closed checkbox question. re-asked again it.When I solved it,It closed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you looking for is a **headless CMS** (Content Management System), I would recommend you to use and integrate with your angular application. Probably you don't want content managers messing with the codebase as well.

**Pros**:

- You have a dedicated dashboard for content manager
- Different roles and permissions (user, admin)
- There's no need to touch in the codebase.
- Locales implementation
- Webhooks (few of them)
- Version control in the content side

**Cons**:

- Most of them are paid
- You need some knowledge and experience to integrate 'nicely' in your
  application
- Some of them, in my experience, has some implementation issues with
  Angular Universal (Server-Side Rendering)

Here's a few that I have used already:

*Contentful*
https://www.contentful.com/

*Storyblok*
https://www.storyblok.com/